# How to specify unit types in SPARQL (wikidata)

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to find the highest mountain in the world

```
SELECT ?mountLabel WHERE {
  ?mount wdt:P31 wd:Q8502.        #mount is-instance-of mountain
  ?mount wdt:P2044 ?height.       #mount elevation-above-sea-level height
  filter(?height = MAX(?height))
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?height)
LIMIT 1
```

This returns the incorrect value since some data entries are stored in feet and not meters.

Comment: What do you think is the meaning of this: `filter(?height = MAX(?height))` ?

Comment: Try this (untested, endpoint is horribly slow currently...): `?mount p:P2044/psn:P2044/wikibase:quantityAmount ?height.`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks that works. Responding to the use of the filter: Since I only need the largest value, the filter should in theory find the max height and remove all entries that are not the max height. Thus being faster that sorting the whole list and taking to top element.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with the filter. `max` is an aggregate function, i.e. it needs grouping. Moreover, it's just used in the projection, e.g. `select ?s (?max(?val) as ?maxVal) ...` or in a `having` clause (which is a "filter" on groups), e.g. `SELECT ... GROUP BY ?s HAVING (?avg(?val) > 2.2)` - see the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates) - if you do it in a sub-query as projection, ok - then you could use the value in the outer query as filter or direct binding.